# OAuth for iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I have project which wants to login with OAuth authentication link the twitter and Facebook OAuth. Is there any library available for OAuth in IOS for the login purpose. If any one know how to do or where to get this library please help me. I tried a lot to create a library with the help of twitter OAuth, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

i got the library f oAuth in iPhone application .this the link for svn,you cn copy paste this svn link to mac terminal and enter,it will utmaticlly download the entire library in your system

```
svn checkout http://mpoauthconnection.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ mpoauthconnection-read-only
```

Thanks.